# Clearing Jquery UI dialog input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code as part of a system to randomly pop up a dialog window every 15-30 minutes, which requires user input to continue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('Are you awake? Please enter your user ID in the following box:<br/><br/><input type="text" id="dialog-input"><p></p></input><br/><br/><button id="timerButton">Yes</button><br/><br/>If you do not press yes within 10 minutes, the office will be contacted.')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Inactivity Monitor'
        });
    });
```

What happens is the dialog window pops up, the user must enter their user ID and press 'yes' to close the dialog box, otherwise an alert will be shown telling them it's wrong. When they enter the correct ID and the dialog window closes, the timer starts again and in 15-30 minutes, the dialog window will pop up again but when it appears again, the user's ID number is still held in the text box. Is there a way to clear this so the box is always empty when it appears?

I tried this with no luck:

```
$("#dialog-input").html("");
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try .val("") instead of html("")

Comment: Thanks, works great..typical that I was trying to wrong word!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
$("#dialog-input").val("");
```

The input's value is hold in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $("#dialog-input").val("");